# Search file for encoded tags

Tags: java, file, search

I have a file I need to search for encoded tags, and retrieve data identified by them. Tags are 4 Bytes long and identify either ascii strings of variable length or two-byte-integer values encoded Little-Endian.

The tags appear to all be on 4 byte boundaries and all within the first 2000 bytes of the start of the file.  I have tried various ways of searching the file.  The only one that has worked has been a byte by byte compare using decimal integer values.

One solution found on SO but not exactly for this problem suggested:  indexOfSubList().
I tried this test but the result is -1.

```
byte[] needle = {68,73,67,77};
byte[] hayStack = {00, 01, 68,73,67,77, 11, 45};
location = Collections.indexOfSubList(Arrays.asList(hayStack), Arrays.asList(needle));
```

I am by no means wedded to this code and would appreciate any other thoughts or solutions.

Comment: "but the result is -1", what would you expect it to be?

Comment: Your example would be *much* more informative if the `hayStack` array actually contained the `needle` array. In that case, `-1` is also returned which is more interesting to consider.

Comment: I've corrected the needle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is kind of vague, do you mean something like this:

```
// simplified way of identifying tag by first byte of it,
// make it more complex as needed
byte startOfTag = 65;

// for loop assumes tags start at even 4 byte boundary, if not, modify loop
for(int i = 0; i <= data.length-4 ; i += 4) {
    if (data[i] == startOfTag) {
        myTagHandlerMethod(data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2], data[i+3]);
    }
}
```

---

You get -1 from `Collections.indexOfSubList`, because `Arrays.asList` does not work as you expect for `byte[]`: it returns `List<byte[]>`, not `List<Byte>`. Containers must contain object references, unboxed numeric types not allowed... This should work:

```
Byte[] needle = {68,73,67,77};
Byte[] hayStack = {00, 01, 68,73,67,77, 11, 45};
location = Collections.indexOfSubList(Arrays.asList(hayStack), Arrays.asList(needle));
```

---

If you want to avoid re-inventing wheel while manipulating primitive type arrays, you can use [Google's Guava libs](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained#Primitive_array_utilities). It has for example an `indexOf` method which you could use here.

Comment: Thank you. Your example and Dunkan Jones works.  Now I'm hung up on trying to read into the Byte[] from the file.  Any ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Mike Just convert byte[] array directly to ArrayList<Byte> with a simple for loop, no need to have any intermediate Byte[] array, I think.

Comment: @Mike one thing to note: Byte[] or ArrayList<Byte> will take about 10 times as much memory as primitive array byte[], so if you can work with primitive array, it's much more efficient. May not matter for a few thousand bytes on modern hardware, but for bigger amounts of data, it is a killer.

Comment: hyde, I am going to go back to primatives. Thanks for your input. --- Mike

Answer (score 1):

By converting your `byte` arrays to `Byte` arrays, you will get the result you desire:

```
Byte[] needle = { 68, 73, 67, 77 };
Byte[] hayStack = { 00, 01, 68, 73, 67, 77, 11, 45 };
location = Collections.indexOfSubList(Arrays.asList(hayStack),
    Arrays.asList(needle));

// location now equals 2
```

This is because `Arrays.asList` doesn't operate as you'd imagine on `byte[]` objects. It returns a `List<byte[]>` rather than a `List<Byte>`.